# Proof verification - Lang's Algebra Chapter 1 problem 43

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm wondering if someone can help me by verifying my proof for problem 43 of Chapter 1 of Lang's Algebra. The problem is as follows:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite abelian group $G$. Prove that $G$ has a subgroup that is isomorphic to $G/H$.

Here is my proof (I think it contains some redundant details; please excuse me for this):

We prove by induction on $|G|$. The base case is trivial.

Let $H\le G$ be a nontrivial subgroup. Say $p$ is a prime divisor of $|H|$. Then $H$ contains a subgroup $P$ of order $p$. We have $(G/P)/(H/P)\cong G/H$. By induction hypothesis, $\bar G=G/P$ contains a subgroup $\bar K$ isomorphic to $G/H$. Lift $\bar K$ back to $G$. We get a subgroup $K\le G$ containing $P$ s.t. $K/P\cong G/H$.

Unless $P=K$, $\bar K$ is proper in $\bar G$, meaning $K$ is proper in $G$. Thus by induction hypothesis, $K$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $K/P\cong G/H$.

If $P=K$, $P$ must lie in the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. But $G$ is isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. Say $G\cong P_1\times...\times P_n$ (the precise isomorphism here is simply taking coordinate-wise sum in $P_1\times...\times P_n$) where $P_i$'s are Sylow subgroups of $G$ and $P\le P_1$. Then $$G/P\cong (P_1\times...\times P_n)/(P\times 0\times...\times 0)\cong (P_1/P)\times P_2\times...\times P_n$$ from which we are done by induction hypothesis if $G$ is not a $p$-group.

Assume $G$ is a $p$-group and say $G$ is of the form $\mathbb Z/{p^{a_1}}\mathbb Z\times...\times \mathbb Z/{p^{a_n}}\mathbb Z$ with $a_i\ge a_{i+1}\ge 1$. Write $A_i=0\times...\times 0\times \mathbb Z/{p^{a_i}}\mathbb Z\times 0\times...\times 0\le G$, so $G\cong A_1\times...\times A_n$. View $P$ as its isomorphic image, a subgroup of $A_1\times...\times A_n$.

Since $P$ is of order $p$, a generator of $P$ must be of the form $({b_1},...,{b_n})$ where $b_i=u_ip^{a_i-1}$ (for some $p\nmid u_i$) or $b_i=0$ (and at least one of $b_i\ne 0$). Pick $m$ to be the largest index s.t. $b_m\ne 0$. Hence we can write the generator as $$\alpha=(b_1,...,b_{m-1},u_mp^{a_m-1},0,...,0)$$ Let $A_m'=\langle\beta\rangle=\langle(c_1,...,c_{m-1},u_m,0,...,0)\rangle$ where $c_i=0$ if $b_i=0$ and $c_i=u_ip^{a_i-a_m}$ if $b_i=u_ip^{a_i-1}$. Note $p^{a_m-1}\beta=\alpha$.

Also note $G\cong A_1\times...\times A_m'\times...\times A_n$ (the precise isomorphism is again the coordinate-wise sum). To see this, note $$(A_1+...+A_{m-1}+A_{m+1}+...+A_n)\cap A_m'=0$$ Since $P\le A_m'$, it follows $G/P\cong A_1\times...\times (A'_m/P)\times...\times A_n$. If $G$ is cyclic, then the result is (almost) trivial; otherwise, we conclude $A'_m$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $A'_m/P$ by induction hypothesis. Thus $G$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G/P$.

Comment: Sort of messy... You know that G is a direct sum of its Sylow subgroups — so is H, and so is G/H, and everything happens in each factor separately: this allows you to reduce your problem to the case in which G is a p-group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Indeed, thanks for your suggestion!